# Why no segfault on null pointer dereference?

Tags: c

I have written this simple C code,

```
int main()
{
        int *p = NULL;
        if (p && *p);
        //if (*p && p);
        return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, unexpectedly I didn't any seg fault. But if I change order of `p` and `*p` in `if ()`(like in the comment) I do get seg fault.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: The first is a standard ideom. You would have found out yourself if you had done a little research. Or if you just had read the description of the `&&` operator. But apparently first asking is easier than learning. Re. the 2nd variant (`*p %% p`): why do you expect a segfault? You invoke  undefined behaviour; think about the meaning of the word **undefined**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The && operator has short-circuit evaluation.  If the result can be determined by just looking at the value of the left operand, then the right operand is not evaluated.  For the && operator, this means that if the left side evaluates to false, it doesn't evaluate the right side, and the result is false.  In other words,

```
if (p && *p) ...
```

is equivalent to

```
if (p) if (*p) ...
```

From the C11 standard, section 6.5.13/4:

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
>   the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

Comment: any reference to your answer?

Comment: @ParthaBera: Added.

Comment: this applies to c also?

Comment: @ParthaBera yes it does apply to C also

Comment: @ParthaBera: Sorry, I didn't notice the C tag.  I've changed my answer to use the equivalent reference from the C11 standard.

Comment: Same applies for `||` (or) phrases
`if (a || b)` where if `a` is `true`, `b` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Sidenote: there is no other standard for the C language tha C11., C99, C90 are not C standards (anymore). Read the foreword of the standard.